# Problem with text message encoding when sending to ActiveMQ with JmsTemplate

Tags: java, spring, encoding, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

When I send text message containing russian characters to ActiveMQ I get abracadabra. I use org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate,  jmsTemplate.convertAndSend. How to specify UTF-8 encoding. Is a problem in the rpoperties of JmsTemplate bean, or maybe in ActiveMq?

Comment: "I get abracadabra". LoL

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved by converting to TextMessage and use jmsTemplate.send(destination, s -> s.createTextMessage(textMsg));